# How to make background image go in the "background" using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, background

I want to fill my page with a background image and have the text aligned in place with that background. With the below code, the background image loads at the top of the page, and the text goes under it. I know I can use the "background: " function, but the way it is done in my below code allows for automatic resizing, regardless of browser size (i.e., mobile devices have small browser sizes). So, I just want the background image to go behind the text.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Title</title>    

<style>

img.bg
{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width; 781;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    z-index: -1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 781)
{
    img.bg
    {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -390.5;
    }
}

#container 
{
    position: relative;
    width: 781;
    margin: 50 px auto;
    height: 758;
    border: 1px solid black
}

#left
{   
    position: relative;
    left: 1.280409731113956%;
    top: 14.51187335092348%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}   

p
{
    font: 14px Georgia;
}

</style>

</head>
```

HTML

```
<img class="bg" src="background.jpg">

<div id="container">

<div id="left">
    <p>
    Text
    </p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't try creating a background image with an `<img />` tag. Use the CSS `background: <color> url('path/to/file.ext') <repeat> <position>;` declaration.

Comment: "I know I can use the CSS 'background: ' function, but the way it is done in my below code allows for automatic resizing, regardless of browser size (i.e., mobile devices have small browser sizes)."

Comment: There has got to be a way to make a background with the <img> tag, because I've done it before. But for some reason, it won't work this way.

Comment: @myom - there is the `background-size` property that you can use. You simply set it to 100% and the background image resizes automatically.

Comment: @Ana, is this in referral to the problem I encounter when using "position: fixed"? I cannot use the "background-size" property when I am not using CSS, but I am using the <img> tag.

Comment: Well, I just tried throwing in position: fixed and background-size:100% into img.bg{} but it didn't work :/

Comment: No, no, I meant when using a background image, not an img tag. I'll update my answer to clear things in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your BG image have a z-index of 1, and your #container div to have a z-index of 2.  Does that work?

```
img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px; /*or whatever top/left values you need*/
}
```

Comment: darn.  I'll check back on this in a little bit when I have more time and if you haven't found a solution, I'm gonna actually test some stuff out with the code you supplied.

Comment: ok i fixed it:  make your img have a "position: absolute" with a "z-index: 1" then on your container, make the "z-index: 2" and "top: 0px" with a "position: relative"...tested and it worked.

Comment: Worked :) Now I just need to make the text move relative to the background image...

Answer (score 2):

Just use `position: fixed` for your background image http://dabblet.com/gist/3136606

```
img.bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 781px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

---

---

***EDIT*** (I wish there was a way to make it more visible than this)

OK, after reading the comments for the original question, I understand that the purpose is to have a background that scales nicely for any display sizes.

Unfortunately, quite a lot of mobile devices have a problem with `position: fixed` - you can read more about this [**here**](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/).

So *the best solution in this case is to use a background image, not an img tag*, having the [**`background-size`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) set to `100%` (which will stretch the image - [**example**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3136688)), or to `cover` (which will scale the image such that it completely covers the screen - [**example**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3136759))

Comment: Unfortunately this zooms into the background when the browser window is maxed out and I cannot scroll down to see the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried using `background-size` and `cover`, but for some reason, this made it so that when my browser window was maximized, it zoomed in to the top of the background image and I could not scroll down to see the rest of the background.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you can also try that css:

```
body{
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

it's should cover all youre page even when page size is changed

Comment: This messes with the text alignment though :/